# Explosion of a Neutron Bomb

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, neutrons, explosions

Watching "The Dark Knight Rises", Bane announces halfway into the movie at the stadium that what they have is a neutron bomb. But then at the end of the movie there is an actual nuclear explosion shown as if it was a fission bomb. My understanding was that a neutron bomb only releases highly energetic particles like neutrons so that all organic matter is destroyed by the radiation. I thought the point was to keep buildings/cities/material wealth intact so that at first you deploy a neutron bomb, kill the people in the city, wait for radiation to settle down, and then move in and take over the city. So a neutron bomb shouldn't blast like that with the ability to level a city and everything in it. Is a neutron bomb supposed to "explode" like that? Did I have the wrong idea? Or is it just another case of Hollywood getting the physics wrong? How much of an "explosion" is a neutron bomb supposed to have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [neutron bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_bomb) is still a hydrogen bomb, just designed in such a way as to allow much of the neutron radiation to escape, instead of remaining trapped to enhance the chain-reaction.

A neutron bomb explosion would be basically the same as a hydrogen bomb, just with a little less explosive energy, and a little more neutron radiation---making it more harmful to people (especially because its harder to shield from neutrons).

Comment: This: fission/fusion/neutron-spalation rather than fission/fusion or fission/fusion/fission as in a high yield thermonuclear explosive.

Comment: The most common designs, as I understand it, were normal H-bombs more or less minus the U238 jacket (final "-fission" step). So yes, as zhermes said, still a big explosion. As a living object, you couldn't really tell the difference before expiring.

Answer (score 0):

Any sufficiently large explosion will produce a mushroom cloud, just due to convection currents cause by heat, which rises and spreads.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).